# Bokeh: chage data of Scatter plot before push_notebook()

Tags: bokeh

My idea is to use Interactor example is provided [in this sample repo](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/0.12.3/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb) however with Bokeh charts (high level abstraction), and not figures (mid level abstraction) as it is in example.

**Code from example**

```
p = figure(title="simple line example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(-5,5))
r = p.line(x, y, color="#2222aa", line_width=3)
def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    elif f == "tan": func = np.tan
    r.data_source.data['y'] = A * func(w * x + phi)
    push_notebook()
```

**My code:**

```
p = Scatter(df_full_2d, x='X', y='Y', color='NPS Class',
            title="Projection of NP Surver to 2D", legend="top_left",
            legend_sort_field = 'color',
            legend_sort_direction = 'ascending',
            xlabel="Feature one",
            ylabel="Feature two",
            width=900,
            height=600)

def update(f, perp=50):
    if perp < 60:
        p.title.text = 'Below'
    else:
        p.title.text = 'Above'
    push_notebook()
```

Title is getting change, but how can I access change data in Scatter?

Thanks in advance!

### Update

I've found way to change data. 
`p.renderers` is a list, 3 elements of which (found experimentally) do represent 3 different groups of dots on my scapper. So  it's possible to refer source of  one group with `p.renderers[1].data_source` however it's a pretty dirty way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't currently recommend using `push_notebook` in conjunction with `bokeh.charts`. The high level charts potentially do things like grouping and aggregations internally, which really means that the entire chart has to be recomputed. But if you are just replacing entire charts, there is no need for `push_notebook` anyway.

However, there are some recent changes that make things even simpler in `bokeh.plotting`. Colormapping can now be done in the browser, and legends can be automatically created by grouping a column. For example as of Bokeh `0.12.3` you can do this:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.palettes import RdBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    y=[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    label=['hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo']
))
color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=['hi', 'lo'], 
                                      palette=[RdBu3[2], RdBu3[0]])

p = figure(x_range=(0, 7), y_range=(0, 3), height=300, tools='save')
p.circle(x='x', y='y', radius=0.5, source=source,
        color={'field': 'label', 'transform': color_mapper},
        legend='label')
show(p)
```

[image]

---

So my strongest suggestion is to stick with `bokeh.plotting` if you want to take advantage of `push_notebook`.